# Get Media ID Instagram

Tags: php, instagram

Below is the code I am using

```
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
var_dump($decode);
```

This results in the below:

```
c.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xfa1/10666256_719752088073218_1127882203_a.jpg" 
["full_name"]=> string(26) "Promote OLShop Harga Murah" ["bio"]=> string(0) "" ["id"]=> 
string(9) "356515767" } } } }
```

How do I get Get Media ID?example results :

```
817757393383064097_356515767
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/gaul/media/recent?access_token=1463408808.e757b44.0738048e481448b48f1cbb23f70f0195&count=1'); 
$decode = json_decode($json, true); 
$media_id = $decode['data'][0]['id']
```

Comment: always put some explanation to the answer you posted, so that others can get it easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you took a look at [Embedding](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/) you would find a suitable answer, for me i was in need for the `media_id` for a project, so i wrapped it into a function

```
function getMediaID($permalink) {

        $ch     = curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=' . $permalink);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $oembed = curl_exec($ch);
                  curl_close($ch);
        $oembed = json_decode($oembed, true);
        return $oembed['media_id'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That result you showed are when getting a USER data... not medias. To get media use some like:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USERID/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN&count=COUNT
```

Where:

- USERID ir the user you want to get medias
- TOKEN is your access token that enable you to use the API
- COUNT to tell how much photos of that user you want to retrieve at this time

Answer (score 0):

code by Bankzilla is working perfectly. I would upvote it , but for my reputation points are less :/. Also the code isnt echoing anything so the page will be blank.
Here is the code to display the media id. Copy it into a file with php extension for ex: getmedia.php and paste url where your are hosting it in browser and run it.
 ex : www.myhost.com/mysite/getmedia.php?url="URL OF THE MEDIA HERE"

```html
<?php

$permalink = $_GET["url"];
getMediaID($permalink) ;




function getMediaID($permalink) {

        $ch     = curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=' . $permalink);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $oembed = curl_exec($ch);
                  curl_close($ch);
        $oembed = json_decode($oembed, true);
  echo $oembed['media_id']; 
        return $oembed['media_id'];

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use:

```
$search_response = curlRequest("get", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token={$json_data['access_token']}");
```

Then:

```
$photo_id= $search_response['data'][$i]['id'];
echo $photo_id .'<br/>';

($i for exapmle data[1] , data[2] etc.) - (each image data)
```